# Compare 2d array in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am looking for an easy way to check if two 2D arrays have the exact same contents. The ideal situation would be to not use any for loops, but if thats the only possible way so be it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider using [`Arrays.deepEquals`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29). :-)

Comment: Theres a damn good reason this is my first place to ask questions! sorry i didn't search javadocs enough! thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

The only way is nested loops or I believe its Array.deepEquals you can check javadocs. Nested loops would be quicker thoe.

Answer (score 0):

However, Arrays.deepEquals is a method that is built with for loops.  The looping structure is probably the best way to solve the issue...it's just that with the pre-built method, then you don't have to build the loops yourself.

Someone correct me if I'm wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using [`Arrays.deepEquals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[])):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class DeepEqualsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a1[][] = new int[][]{ {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} };
        int a2[][] = new int[][]{ {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} };

        if (Arrays.deepEquals(a1, a2)) {
            System.out.println("Arrays are equal");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Arrays are not equal");
        }

    }
}
```