# Comparing 2D arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Im trying to compare two 2D arrays by using this. But I keep getting "**Arrays are not the same.**" even when they are the same.

```
     int i;
     int j = 0;
     int k;
     int l;

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> zero = new ArrayList<Integer>();

 for ( i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
    list.add(i);


}

//System.out.println(list); //[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
Collections.shuffle(list.subList(1, 15));
System.out.println(list);

Collections.replaceAll(list, 16, 0);
   System.out.println(list);


// System.out.println(list); //[11, 5, 10, 9, 7, 0, 6, 1, 3, 14, 2, 4, 15, 13, 12, 8]

int[][] a2 = new int[4][4];
int [][] a3 = new int[4][4];
for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for ( j = 0;  j< 4; j++) {


        a2[i][j] = list.get(i*4 + j);
        a3[i][j] = list.get(i*4 + j);
    }

}
for (int[] row : a2) {
System.out.print("[");
for (   int a : row)
    System.out.printf("%4d", a);
System.out.println("]");
}
for (int[] row : a3) {
System.out.print("[");
for (   int a : row)
    System.out.printf("%4d", a);
System.out.println("]");
}
 boolean check1 = Arrays.equals(a2, a3);
if(check1 == false)
System.out.println("Arrays are not same.");
else
System.out.println("Both Arrays are same.");
```

I can't do it like this either. 
     boolean check1 = Arrays.equals(a2[i][j], a3[i][j]);

Comment: That's because you can't compare 2D arrays like that.

Comment: By checking one 1D row at a time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare 2d array in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768945/compare-2d-array-in-java)

Comment: Sorry took me a second to use the search for you.

Comment: OK. But I can't do this, Arrays.equals(a2[i][j], a3[i][j]).

Comment: instead of printing arrays the hard way, use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));`, no formatting per element though, full precision will be printed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first one does not work because a two-D int array is really an array of arrays (that is, an array of objects). The `Arrays.equals()` method for an array of objects uses `equals()` to test whether corresponding elements are equal. Unfortunately for your code, `equals()` for arrays is the default `Object` implementation: they are `equal()` only if they are the identical object. In your case, they are not.

In the second case, when you code `Arrays.equals` and pass two `int` values, the compiler can't match it to any signature of the `Arrays` class.

One way to check equality is to use deepEquals:

```
boolean check1 = Arrays.deepEquals(a2, a3);
```

Another way is to iterate the outer array explicitly:

```
boolean check1 = true;
for (int i = 0; check1 && i < a2.length; ++i) {
    check1 = Arrays.equals(a2[i], a3[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
boolean check1 = Arrays.deepEquals(a2, a3);
```

is definitely a possibility. The implementation of that uses `Object[]`, which may be appealing to you because it checks the types of the arrays you pass on-the-fly.

But if you want stronger typing and a little less overhead, you can write your own as follows.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Operations on multi-dimensional arrays.
 * 
 * @author stephen harrison
 */
public class ArrayUtils {
    private ArrayUtils() {
        // Static methods only
    }

    public static <T> boolean equals(final T[][] a, final T[][] b) {
        if (a == b) {
            return true;
        }

        if (a == null || b == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (a.length != b.length) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
            if (!Arrays.equals(a[i], b[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static <T> boolean equals(final T[][][] a, final T[][][] b) {
        if (a == b) {
            return true;
        }

        if (a == null || b == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (a.length != b.length) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
            if (!equals(a[i], b[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The first `equals` on 2D arrays calls `Arrays.equals()`. The 3D version similarly calls the 2D one.

I hope that helps.